# How to check multiple values in a key while checking the constant?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I've been trying to figure this out for long time and none of the SO articles I find on this work.

I have the following to work with in concept...

```
'dependency' => array('Value', '==', 'true'),
'dependency' => array('Value1', '==', 'true'),
'dependency' => array('Value2', '==', 'true'),
'dependency' => array('Value3', '==', 'true'),
'dependency' => array('Value4', '==', 'true'),
```

But, I need "Value" to contain Value1, Value2, Value3, and Value4.

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried so many things, so maybe I am just string this together wrong because I have tried...

[array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php),
[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php),
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php),
[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php),

and several $variable methods, but nothing has worked.

Can somebody help and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Like `'dependency' => array(array('Value','Value1', etc), '==', 'true')` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that though with the framework I am using and I guess this doesn't work, but your comment is right.

Comment: Maybe someone important will see this. This question got marked negative. SO should let someone know in a notification format why a question got negatives with suggestions on how to improve. I see that it had a text hover comment saying my question showed no search effort which is way beyond correct. That text hover needs a more general or accurate text. I said in the beginning I searched for the answer, which I did for almost 2 hours before asking. That is highly indicated by the php.net array links I gave. I gave the code in concept as to what I was trying to achieve so it would be obvious.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]. You need to specify the outcome as well. For instance, I *had* to ask you for a clarification. That shouldn't be needed.   Also, you can specify what *exactly* you tried (and what failed). And by that i mean some code, not links to php functions. But don't worry, the more you interact with SO, the more you learn ;)

Comment: Also, if you feel that the community's reactions were harsh, you can always post a question on [meta].

Comment: @AlexTartan thanks. I will do those things next time. I didn't initially because I didn't want to take 90-120 minutes of different things I tried and write a long, drawn out codeful question. Not because I can't or wouldn't, but because I didn't want to complicate or overwhelm a user with things I may have tried that were totally in the wrong direction, haha :) But I will make sure to do those things next time while still trying to simplify the format of the question. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an array in your array like this:

```
'dependency' => array(array("value1", "Value2", "Value3"), '==', 'true'),
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that though with the framework I am using and I guess this doesn't work, but your comment is right. So I submitted the issue/question to the framework author.

Comment: Just to add this is supported, at least in my theme's framework, which may or may not work the same as in regular php. 'dependency' => array(array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"), '==|==|==', 'true|true|true'),